# Multiple statements in .onAppear() not working

Tags: xcode, swiftui

In my code I am attempting to set two variables in an .onAppear() modifier. The code appears to go into an infinite loop calling the .onAppear() modifier over and over again. Eliminating either one of the two assignments has the expected outcome. Using two .onAppear() modifiers, with one statement each also works as expected (which is my work-around).

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ChartView: View {
    @State private var isLocked = false
    @State private var isOffset = false
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("test")
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.isLocked = true
            //self.isOffset = true
        })
        .onAppear {
            //self.isLocked = true
            self.isOffset = true
        }
        .onAppear {
            //self.isLocked = true
            //self.isLocked = true
        }
        .onReceive(timer, perform: { t in
            print("Timer fired \(t) with lock \(self.isLocked)")
        })
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ChartView())
```

In the code above are three .onAppear() modifiers (in my final code I would have only one), if I have zero or one statement enabled in all three blocks the code executes as expected. If I have any block with both statements enabled the code goes into an infinite loop and the timer never fires.

Using Xcode 12.3 in Playground on an iMac, as well as targeted to an iOS app running on an iPad. Also occurs in the Playground app run on an iPad.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its an apparent bug, but keep in mind every time @state is update, the view may update as well.

one work around is to use Bool.toggle(), instead of update the value direct.

This way reminds us with a better or careful design only when we need to.

```
ZStack {
        Text("test")
    }.onAppear {
        if !self.isLocked { self.isLocked.toggle()}
        if !self.isOffset { self.isOffset.toggle()}
    }.onReceive(timer, perform: { t in
        print("Timer fired \(t) with lock \(self.isLocked)")
    })
```